# Is the resolution of a sub-sheaf into complex of holomorphic vector bundles a "sub-resolution"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $F\rightarrow X$ be a coherent sheaf on a projective Kahler manifold. We can resolve it into a complex of holomorphic vector bundles $E^{\bullet}\rightarrow X$. Let $G\subset F$ be a subsheaf of $F$, that we resolve into a complex $V^{\bullet}\rightarrow X$.

Can we compare the two resolution $E^{\bullet}$ and $V^{\bullet}$? In particular can we say $V^{\bullet}\subset E^{\bullet}$ ?

Comment: You can find compatible resolutions, but not every pair of resolutions is compatible (just consider the special case of a non-locally-free ideal sheaf inside the structure sheaf where the resolution of the structure sheaf is the complex concentrated in degree zero that is the structure sheaf itself).

Comment: @JasonStarr what do you mean by a compatible resolution?

Comment: By "compatible resolution" I mean a resolution $V^\bullet$ of the subsheaf $G$ that admits a chain homomorphism to the resolution $E^\bullet$ of the sheaf $F$ inducing the inclusion homomorphism $G\hookrightarrow F$ and such that the individual homomorphisms of the chain homomorphism are injective sheaf homomorphisms.  I believe this is what you asked about.

Comment: @JasonStarr that was indeed the question. Can I always find such compatible resolutions? Its not clear from your first comment.

Comment: Yes, you can always find such a resolution.  This follows from the (graded case of the) “Horseshoe Lemma” in homological algebra.